# Geometric and holomorphic structure of $\mathbb{C} \rtimes \mathbb{C} \setminus \{ 0 \}$

Tags: complex-geometry, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

Put $G= \mathbb{C} \rtimes_{\phi} \mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$ where $\phi_{a} (z)= az$ for $a \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$.
$G$ is a real $4$ dimensional Lie group;  then it has a unique left invariant metric which restricts to the standard Euclidean metric at the neutral element. Let $I(G)$ be the group of isometries of $G$ with respect to this invariant  metric.

On the other hand $G$ is an open subset of the complex Euclidean space. The group of holomorphic automorphisms of $G$ is denoted by $Aut(G)$.

> We constructed $G$ as an obvious  generalization of the $2$ dimensional  Lie group $H= \mathbb{R} \rtimes \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$, the Poincare upper half plane.
>   We know that the group of holomorphic automorphisms of $H$ preserves the left invariant metric of $H$.
>
> Now a natural question is: What is the structure of $Aut(G)$? What geometric structure  on $G$ is preserved by $Aut(G)$?

Are there any relations between $I(G)$ and $Aut(G)$?

Is there a precise description for these  two groups?

> Considering $G$ as an open set in $\mathbb{C}^2$, is it true to say that all geodesics are either closed  or perpendicular to the boundary? (Perpendicular with respect to the usual geometry of $\mathbb{C}^2 = \mathbb{R}^4$?

Comment: $G$ is isomorphic to the group of upper triangular matrices in $\mathrm{PGL}_2(\mathbf{C}$; it acts transitively by isometries (fixing a boundary point) on the 3-dimensional hyperbolic space and thus can probably be seen inside its unit tangent bundle. Computing the automorphism group is an exercise using the Lie algebra; in particular its unit component is made of the inner automorphisms.

Comment: @YCor  I think G is isomorphic to all matrices with (a, b,0, a). A on diagonal. But could you please explain on remaining part of your  comment?(or please give a reference)

Comment: No, the group you mention is commutative.

Comment: @YCor  yes i was incorrect

Comment: @YCor  regarding the automorphism group, are you saying every bi holomirphic map on G is an inner group automorphism provided it is homotopic to identity?

Comment: ...if it's homotopic to the identity among holomorphic group automorphisms

Comment: @YCor  are there some vector fields in its Lie algebra which foliate G with closed geodesics?